# Extract Date from datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 10, 5, 30, tzinfo=tzlocal()

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a requirement to write a python code to extract date only from InstalledTime

```
{'Title': '2020-06 Servicing Stack Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB4562253)', 'KBId': 'KB4562253', 'Classification': 'SecurityUpdates', 'Severity': 'Critical', 'State': 'Installed', 'InstalledTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 10, 5, 30, tzinfo=tzlocal())}
```

Once its extracted need to subtract it with the timenow ie date and find the number of days in btwn.

Please help on this .

Comment: Have you read the `datetime` documentation? What is your specific question?

Comment: It doesn't need to be extracted because its already a datetime object. Something has already parsed it into a python object.

Comment: I need to write a python code to have this extraction of date

Comment: How do I find the number of days between the extracted date and current date ?

Comment: What exactly should be the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import datetime
import dateutil.tz

result = {
    'Title': '2020-06 Servicing Stack Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB4562253)',
    'KBId': 'KB4562253',
    'Classification': 'SecurityUpdates',
    'Severity': 'Critical',
    'State': 'Installed',
    'InstalledTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 10, 5, 30, tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzlocal())
}
install_time = result["InstalledTime"]
# Create a timezone aware date for right now
right_now = datetime.datetime.now(dateutil.tz.tzlocal())
diff = right_now - install_time
print(diff.days)
```

I am assuming you have [dateutil.tz.tzlocal](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html?highlight=tzlocal#tzlocal-examples) because the `tzinfo` attribute of your example is `tzlocal()`.

In order to subtract two `datetime.datetime` objects, they must both either be naive or both be timezone aware.

Also, `diff.days` may not be robust because of [normalization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).